# How to detect scroll event from two UIScrollView( super-sub)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

There are two scrollviews. one is the other's superView.

I found sometimes the super-scrollview is tracked and sometimes the sub-scrollview is tracked when i dragging on the sub-scrollview different times.

Especially, at the position end of sub-scrollview at which will trigger bounce event, the super-scrollview is tracked most of the time.

so how does the (ios)system to decide which scrollview is tracked?
and what can do if i want drag on the position of sub-scrollview, the sub-scrollview is tracked to response the scroll event, if i drag on the position out of sub-scrollview's area, the super-scrollview response the scroll event.

Comment: Are you overriding the `scrollViewDidScroll` method of `ScrollView`?

Comment: Is the question how you as a developer can detect this or how iOS (the system) decide which scrollview to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to have nested scrollviews. But in case you must have them, you can do it by disabling scrolling on both the UIScrollViews and implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the container UIView. You can then change the offset of both the scrollviews programmatically however you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, i solved the problem by using "underView's Gesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(upView's gesture)"